# Google Sign In - prevent automatic load

Tags: google-signin, google-oauth

I've been stuck on this for hours. I've tried google searching for answers but I don't understand any of them and have to assume it's out of date code.

I'm trying to add a 'sign in with google' to my site but I want it only to redirect to the login-check IF the user hits the button, not as soon as it detects I'm already logged in.

The button:

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId());
    console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
    var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
    window.location.replace("googleLogin.phptoken="+ id_token);
    }
</script>
```

Anyone conquered this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I cant really remember what I did to fix this issue but i had the same one ended up making a new script here is a link to a js fiddle you will have to plug in your own client id and it doesn't have an image so you will just see a broken picture for the google login button.

```
var googleUser = {};
 var startApp = function() {
gapi.load('auth2', function(){
  // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
  auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
    client_id: '83******98-pe4uneu******sj.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
    // Request scopes in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
    //scope: 'additional_scope'
  });
  attachSignin(document.getElementById('customBtn'));
});
};

function attachSignin(element) {
console.log(element.id);
auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
    function(googleUser) {
   first_name =  googleUser.getBasicProfile().getGivenName();
         last_name =  googleUser.getBasicProfile().getFamilyName();
         email =  googleUser.getBasicProfile().getEmail();
        console.log(googleUser.getBasicProfile().getGivenName());
        console.log(googleUser.getBasicProfile().getFamilyName());
        console.log(googleUser.getBasicProfile().getEmail());
        window.location = "/profile"     
    }, function(error) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
    });

 }

 startApp();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/josephmckenzie/9pxc41kx/

All the code you should need is in the js fiddle